# QGIS Vector-/ Raster Import of multiple non-spatially registered datasets

Tags: qgis, georeferencing

When you import multiple spatially unregistered datasets and you want to set the same coordinate system to all data you have to set it for every dataset separately in the import dialogue.

Is there a way to remember your decision so that you have to specify the coordinate system only once?

Comment: I tried checking the import dialogue, normally i would expect to set a marker for "remember this setting" or "do this for all currently selected items".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the behaviour of QGIS when new layer is created or a layer has no CRS. Go to Settings->Options... in the menu and select CRS tab.

[image]

In the middle of the dialogbox check "Use project CRS" or "Use default CRS" to set CRS automaticly.